# Chrome Title Bar: Doesn't match theme

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface

About a week ago I realized that my Google Chrome title bar was gray.

Does anyone know how to fix this UI bug for Google Chrome [Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)]?

After selecting the 'Use system title bar and borders' option, I still have a gray tab bar (instead of the elementary os light gray)

I am running elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit)

Here is a screenshot of the title bar:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Paul, I was able to find the setting to use the "Classic Theme":

[image: before]

Unfortunately, my OCD could not handle the slight difference shown between the title bar and the tab bar in the screenshot above.

That's when I installed the Freya Theme for Google:

[image: after]

I prefer this one because it is **perfect**.

I could link to this, but I need at least 10 repuation to post more than 2 links, and I am the worst.

Comment: Here is the [Freya Theme for Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/freya-theme-for-google-ch/nofpaaefcomkhdkeihhnonlmhajfadgd?hl=en-GB)

Comment: That's my theme! Awesome!

Comment: Chrome 54 on Loki seems to be much better sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this by going into settings>appearance and then clicking the tab that says "Use Classic Theme". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Classic blue theme is quite acceptable solution.
It is not as classic as it is named, but it has another colors for active and inactive window, at least.